# Incorrect directory data for output

Tags: powershell, powershell-1.0

The following code will grab a directory and create menu items for each one. It works fine up until the Add_Click portion; for some reason it just spits out the same file no matter what button has been clicked.

```
$directory = Get-ChildItem -Path ($relative_path + "/scripts")

foreach ($file in $directory) 
{
    $mnuTemp = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.MenuItem
    $mnuTemp.Text = $file.Name
    $mnuTemp.Add_Click({Write-Host $file.Name})
    $mnuScripts.MenuItems.Add($mnuTemp)
}
```

Comment: Is that "same file" the first one in the `$directory` collection, the last one, or some arbitrary one in the middle? Is it always the same one, or does it vary?

Comment: It is always the last one scanned.

Comment: Then you'll need to post more of your script. It sounds like `$mnuScripts.MenuItems` holds only a single `MenuItem` and that item is being overwritten on each iteration of the `foreach`, instead of a collection being appended to. Are you somehow suppressing errors? There is no `Add_Click` method for the `System.Windows.Forms.MenuItem` object that I can see [in the docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.menuitem.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You are still passing a reference to *$file.name* when you added the click command.

```
$mnuTemp.Add_Click({Write-Host $file.Name})
```

You need to pass a reference to a fully evaluated scriptblock instead.

```
$mnuTemp.Add_Click([scriptblock]::Create("write-host $($file.name)"))
```

I have edited your code with the changes below.

```
$directory = Get-ChildItem -Path ($relative_path + "/scripts")

foreach ($file in $directory) 
{
    $mnuTemp = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.MenuItem
    $mnuTemp.Text = $file.Name
    $mnuTemp.Add_Click([scriptblock]::Create("write-host $($file.name)"))
    $mnuScripts.MenuItems.Add($mnuTemp)
}
```